# 404 posts error after 301 redirection of changed category / tag base

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess

I have set category and tag base as below..

Category: News, which makes category url as domain.com/News/category-name

Tag: News-List, which makes tag url as domain.com/News-List/tag-name

After that i redirected old urls to new urls...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^category/(.*) http://domain.com/News/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*) http://domain.com/News-List/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Issue is my custom permalink structure which is /%category%/%postname%/

And all the posts / pages result in 404 error.

What i am missing in redirection rule??

Answer (score -2):

try to go under "Settings" -> "Permalink" and save again the settings. You need to flush the permalink

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?